# Create authorized_keys entry without ssh-keygen

Tags: openssh, ssh-keys

I am working on a system which has `openssl` installed, but not `ssh-keygen`.  I cannot install new software. I can generate an SSH keypair using `openssl`:

```
sh-4.2$ openssl genrsa -out key.pem 2048
Generating RSA private key, 2048 bit long modulus
....................................................................................+++
...............................+++
unable to write 'random state'
e is 65537 (0x10001)
sh-4.2$ openssl rsa -in key.pem -outform PEM -pubout -out key.pub
writing RSA key
sh-4.2$ cat key.pub
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAvGwJnfrGGvHyEigIdSg1
rZFhe+5412j4+bCdtmArUuBna6hXLs5CqJ+cmnUK8hHV7Z9t81vINAWqbNTEQfc6
PU9meCnk1RRQPqm8MeE+G5EDkyZUIanoWhT2yN46sMKEq3ChCW7Ubw+Q42BIrUIE
7pChkG0SH4TlgimkJHmV2ydE6gVlRw+EWbZzqK+IF8xjyDs7xCEmH04AoEV8mwcP
+JziGPiijArgf9M53DEYldVJFPXpti0CqDuW33ZQoiuwV1xnrEgu6kU0M/Ct6WTA
A2dgG8b17SSsL3AYxQy6YWQzD6bZ99U0sj9dW7BM3UPa/wlkgF0hHkFzPb1CBeoY
twIDAQAB
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
sh-4.2$
```

Ordinarily I would then use `ssh-keygen` to generate the required OpenSSH format for `authorized_keys` files:

```
sh-4.2$ ssh-keygen -f key.pub -i -mPKCS8
ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAABAQC8bAmd+sYa8fISKAh1KDWtkWF77njXaPj5sJ22YCtS4GdrqFcuzkKon5yadQryEdXtn23zW8g0Baps1MRB9zo9T2Z4KeTVFFA+qbwx4T4bkQOTJlQhqehaFPbI3jqwwoSrcKEJbtRvD5DjYEitQgTukKGQbRIfhOWCKaQkeZXbJ0TqBWVHD4RZtnOor4gXzGPIOzvEISYfTgCgRXybBw/4nOIY+KKMCuB/0zncMRiV1UkU9em2LQKoO5bfdlCiK7BXXGesSC7qRTQz8K3pZMADZ2AbxvXtJKwvcBjFDLphZDMPptn31TSyP11bsEzdQ9r/CWSAXSEeQXM9vUIF6hi3
sh-4.2$
```

However **I do not have `ssh-keygen` on this system**.  How can I generate the required output using only `openssl` and basic utilities?

Comment: Thanks, corrected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generate the key pair elsewhere, convert it using local tools, then copy it *to* your target machine.

---

The binary structure of an SSHv2 RSA public key (i.e. the long Base64-encoded blob) is:

```
  string    "ssh-rsa"
  mpint     e
  mpint     n
```

where each field is preceded by a 4-byte length value.

Your example shows Bash 4.2 being available on the system, and presumably you also have standard text utilities such as 'sed', so you can use:

```
#!/bin/bash

wr_string() {
        local str=$1
        local lenfmt=$(printf %08x "${#str}" | sed 's/../\\x&/g')
        printf "$lenfmt%s" "$str"
}

wr_mpint() {
        local str=$1
        if [[ $str == [89ABCDEFabcdef]* ]]; then str=0$str; fi
        if (( ${#str} % 2 )); then str=0$str; fi
        local strfmt=$(printf %s "$str" | sed 's/../\\x&/g')
        local lenfmt=$(printf %08x "$[${#str}/2]" | sed 's/../\\x&/g')
        printf "$lenfmt$strfmt"
}

e=$(openssl rsa -in "$1" -pubin -noout -text | sed -n 's/Exponent: .* (0x\([0-9a-f]*\))/\1/ip')
n=$(openssl rsa -in "$1" -pubin -noout -modulus | sed 's/^Modulus=//')

data=$({ wr_string ssh-rsa; wr_mpint "$e"; wr_mpint "$n"; } | openssl base64)
data=${data//$'\n'}

echo "ssh-rsa $data"
```

Invoke the script as `bash convert.sh key.pub`. This will accept **RSA keys only.**

Answer (score 0):

What about generating the ssh key pair on another machine and transfer it?
(via usb or just uploading it to a private web space to download it on the target via some means like wget (or even curl))?

I don't know if this would be an option in your particular situation.

I am just not sure if the key you created with openssl will work (if suitably formatted). ssh-keygen has options to reformat both public and private keys (but you do not have it locally as you stated).